# Developing an interactive shell

Tags: c++, python, interpreter, interactive-shell

I have an application; to interact with it I have to develop an interactive shell. The shell will take input from user and dispatch it to the server, which will process and return a response.

In the past I have done such things, but they typically had the following format:

```
Shell>> COMMAND arg1 arg2 arg3 ..
```

and my implementation was in a manner similiar to:

```
/* Mock implementation */
while(true) {
   in = readline()
   tokens = in.split(' ') //split based on space
   switch(token[0])  {
      case "Command_a": processA(token[1], token[2])
      case "Command_b": processB(token[1], token[2], token[3])
   }
}
```

This time I have to work with more extensive grammar for user input. If I use my current approach, it will make things very difficult with lots of `if , if-elseif-else, if-else, switch` statements for both parsing and generating response.

How can I approach this problem in a manner that will make the interpreter modular and maintainable? What are some ways in which popular CLI-Interface are implemented? I will really appreciate some code examples.

PS: Language choices limited C++/Python

Comment: What is the "extensive grammar of user input"? It can be from "free-form English" (that takes serious AI support to parse) to exactly what you have had before (that takes the switch clause to parse).

Comment: What would some expected user input look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop your own parser and interpreter using bison and flex, but probably wiser is to embed an existing interpreter like Python, Lua or Squirrel.

Comment: But users will not be programmers

Comment: But it is fairly easy syntax and not elaborate as a programming language.

Comment: @WeaklyTyped Have you actually looked at the syntax to scheme (the default language behind Guile, the GNU extension language)? It's very, very simple.

Comment: I agree Scheme is great as an extension language. There are other good implementations suitable for embedding in C or C++ programs, for example http://code.google.com/p/chibi-scheme/

Comment: But Scheme's legendary parenthesis as well as the mere look and feel will create serious UX issues among users.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html), or just embed Lua as others suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) module in Python, perhaps with the addition of [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) should fit your needs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the cmd module :

The Cmd class provides a simple framework for writing line-oriented command interpreters. These are often useful for test harnesses, administrative tools, and prototypes that will later be wrapped in a more sophisticated interface.